laravel docx file not converting to pdf
In laravel I am converting docx file to pdf but i got error
Internal Server Error: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Namespace prefix m on oMath is not defined in Entity, line: 1"

my laravel code is
public function upload_article_image(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        Log::error("file: {$file}");

        if (!$file) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'No file uploaded.'], 400);
        }

        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Log::error("extension: {$extension}");

        try {
            if ($extension === 'pdf') {
                // Store PDF file
                $path = $file->store('public');
            } elseif (in_array($extension, ['doc', 'docx'])) {
                Log::error("docx");

                // Convert DOC/DOCX to PDF
                $pdfPath = $this->convertToPDF($file->getRealPath());
                Log::error("pdfPaths: {$pdfPath}");

                if (!$pdfPath || !file_exists($pdfPath)) {
                    throw new \Exception("Failed to convert the document to PDF.");
                }

                $path = Storage::putFile('public', new \Illuminate\Http\File($pdfPath));
                Log::error("path: {$path}");

            } else {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unsupported file format. Only PDF, DOC, and DOCX are allowed.'], 400);
            }

            $fileName = basename($path); // Extract the filename
            return response()->json(['url' => $fileName])->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::error('File conversion error: ' . $e->getMessage());
            \Log::error('Stack Trace: ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Internal Server Error: ' . $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }

    private function convertToPDF($file)
    {
        $pdfPath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'phpword_') . '.pdf';

        // Set PDF renderer for PhpWord
        Settings::setPdfRendererName(Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF);
        Settings::setPdfRendererPath(base_path('vendor/dompdf/dompdf'));

        $phpWord = IOFactory::load($file);
        $xmlWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'PDF');
        $xmlWriter->save($pdfPath);

        return $pdfPath;
    }

I don't get this error on all docx file . i got that error on specific docx files only .when I convert same docx file to pdf via online tools it converts that file which means that file is not corrupted .
